# Agregar Filas a una tabla con React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

quiero hacer un efecto de `expand - collapse`  pero no funciona, de hecjo en `Firefox` si funciona, pero en `Chrome` no se expande

```
function Row({
    item,
    ExpandData,
    headers
  }) {
    const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <TableRow>
          {headers.map((it) => (
            <TableCell key={v4()} component='th' scope='row'>
              <Box >
                {it.type == 'render'
                  ? item[it.data]({
                      params: item.params || item.item,
                      setExpand: () => setExpand(!expand),
                      expand: expand
                    })
                  : item[it.data]}
              </Box>
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
        {expand ? (
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell component='th' scope='row' colSpan={headers.length}>
              <Box className='expanded'>
                <ExpandData
                  params={item.params || { ...item }}
                  item={{ ...(item.item || item) }}
                />
              </Box>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
  
  export default Row;
```

quiero lograr el efecto de expandir pero no funciona en `Chrome`, solo en `Firefox`

algo como esto https://codesandbox.io/s/expandable-table-row-material-ui-tr3ut?file=/demo.js

Comment: Saludos, lo acabo de probar en Chrome y si que me ha funcionado. abriendo la dirección https://tr3ut.csb.app/ en mi navegador.